# Does the Chronometer Widget start by itself?

Tags: android, counter, chronometer

I initialized a Chronometer Widget like the  normal way:

```
mChronometer = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.chron);
```

And although I dont start the Chronometer it begins to count. 
Why do this happen? And how can I avoid this?

Comment: you never call `start()` at any point ?

Comment: No I never call start().

Comment: Oh yes, sorry. I call .start() in a method, but this method I never call at this moment.

Comment: are you sure ? can you post more code ?